# Build forests with builders

Tags: civilization-6

I once was able to build forests with builders in game but forgot how. I suppose there's a certain tech that enabled me to do that or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the Conservation tech, which allows builders to plant forests, among other things.